# Use names in one df to create same column copies of another dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, copy

```r
df <- structure(list(Cars = structure(3:1, .Label = c("Ford ", "Mazda", "Merc"), class = "factor"), Model = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("c", "e-class", "gt"), class = "factor"), Color = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Black ", "Blue", "Red"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
argument <- structure(list(NewVar = structure(3:2, .Label = c("", "SKU", "Vehicle"), class = "factor"), Input = structure(2:3, .Label = c("", "Cars", "Model"), class = "factor")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
after <- structure(list(Cars = structure(3:1, .Label = c("Ford ", "Mazda", "Merc"), class = "factor"), Model = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("c", "e-class", "gt"), class = "factor"), Color = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Black ", "Blue", "Red"), class = "factor"), Vehicle = structure(3:1, .Label = c("Ford ", "Mazda", "Merc"), class = "factor"), SKU = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("c", "e-class", "gt"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
df
#>    Cars   Model  Color
#> 1  Merc e-class Black 
#> 2 Mazda       c   Blue
#> 3 Ford       gt    Red
argument
#>    NewVar Input
#> 1 Vehicle  Cars
#> 2     SKU Model
after
#>    Cars   Model  Color Vehicle     SKU
#> 1  Merc e-class Black     Merc e-class
#> 2 Mazda       c   Blue   Mazda       c
#> 3 Ford       gt    Red   Ford       gt
```

I am trying to for loop through the columns and create a copy based off the "argument" `data.frame`. This is what I tried but it's not really working. I have the `df`, the argument, and after `dputs`. Essentially, the argument has a column titled "new var", and "input".
In argument, I have "Vehicle" in the "new var" and "input" in "Cars". 
This means within original `df`, copy "Cars" and title it "Vehicle". 
`List` is dynamic so I am trying to keep it in for loops based off of length of the arguments, i.e. changing if I also want color to be copied as paint.

```r
for (i in 1:length(argument$Input) ){
  df %>%   
  mutate( paste0(argument[i,1]) =  !!as.name(argument[i,2])
     }
```

Note, `argument[i,1]` refers to the `input`, so that "variable" is the new column name.
In `dplyr`, this is affecting `df`, so i thought `!!as.name` would pull that variable that already exists i.e. "Cars" is already within before `df`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can select the columns of interest with 'Input' column of 'argument', then use `rename_at` to change the column names.  The 'argument' dataset columns are `factor` class, convert it to `character` while doing the changes.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(as.character(argument$Input)), list(new= ~ .)) %>% 
    rename_at(vars(matches('new')), ~ as.character(argument[[1]]))
#     Cars   Model  Color Vehicle     SKU
#1  Merc e-class Black     Merc e-class
#2 Mazda       c   Blue   Mazda       c
#3 Ford       gt    Red   Ford       gt
```

---

If we are using the OP's `for` loop with `:=`, make sure to evaluate (`!!`) the name strings on the `lhs` of `:=`

```
library(magrittr)
for(i in seq_len(nrow(argument))){
     df %<>%
         mutate(!! as.character(argument[[1]][i]) :=  
                 !! rlang::sym(as.character(argument[[2]][i])))
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a base R option, which can sometimes be easier to use when you already have character column names. Note the coercion to character because your provided data is given as factors.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(Cars = structure(3:1, .Label = c("Ford ", "Mazda", "Merc"), class = "factor"), Model = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("c", "e-class", "gt"), class = "factor"), Color = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Black ", "Blue", "Red"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
argument <- structure(list(NewVar = structure(3:2, .Label = c("", "SKU", "Vehicle"), class = "factor"), Input = structure(2:3, .Label = c("", "Cars", "Model"), class = "factor")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
after <- structure(list(Cars = structure(3:1, .Label = c("Ford ", "Mazda", "Merc"), class = "factor"), Model = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("c", "e-class", "gt"), class = "factor"), Color = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Black ", "Blue", "Red"), class = "factor"), Vehicle = structure(3:1, .Label = c("Ford ", "Mazda", "Merc"), class = "factor"), SKU = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("c", "e-class", "gt"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

add_column <- function(df, new_col, existing_col) {
  new_col <- as.character(new_col)
  existing_col <- as.character(existing_col)
  df[[new_col]] <- df[[existing_col]]
  return(df)
}

for (i in 1:nrow(argument)) {
  df <- add_column(df, argument$NewVar[i], argument$Input[i])
}

df
#>    Cars   Model  Color Vehicle     SKU
#> 1  Merc e-class Black     Merc e-class
#> 2 Mazda       c   Blue   Mazda       c
#> 3 Ford       gt    Red   Ford       gt
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>